# Perl Drush Command script error

Tags: perl, drupal-6, drush

I'm trying to add php code snippet into a Drupal web form node.  I'm getting the error message syntax error near unexpected token `(' which is occurring on the line below the Drupal Query comment.  Any help?  I escaped the parens and dollar signs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $updatesdir = '/var/www/html/mysite/releaseupdates/spint1';
my $drupalroot = '/var/www/html/mysite/web';
my $drushcmd = '/usr/bin/drush';

# Drupal Query
system("$drushcmd -r $drupalroot -u sites.admin --yes sql-query 'update node_revisions set body = REPLACE\(body,\'</div>\',\'<?php \$contact_us_node = abc_drupal_node_load\(NULL, \'my_group\'\);if \(isset\(\$contact_us_node->field_contact_us_message_body\)\) {echo \$contact_us_node->field_contact_us_message_body[0][\'value\'] . \"<br />\";}?></div>\'\) WHERE nid=123'") == 0 or die "$drushcmd failed: $?";
print "Contact Us Body Text updated with PHP Code.\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing this string to `system`, and thus your shell (formatted for better readability):

```
/usr/bin/drush
  -r /var/www/html/mysite/web
  -u sites.admin
  --yes sql-query '
    update node_revisions
    set body = REPLACE(body,'</div>',
        '<?php
          $contact_us_node = abc_drupal_node_load(NULL, 'my_group');
          if (isset($contact_us_node->field_contact_us_message_body)) {
            echo $contact_us_node->field_contact_us_message_body[0]['value'] . "<br />";
          }
        ?></div>'
    )
    WHERE nid=123'
```

Why? Perl's double quoted strings ignore unknown escapes by removing the backslash. For example: `"\(" eq "("`. This means that when the shell sees that command, all those backslashes are missing! Let's see what “strings” the shell actually sees:

```
/usr/bin/drush
-r
/var/www/html/mysite/web
-u
sites.admin
--yes
sql-query
'update node_revisions set body = REPLACE(body,'
</div>
','
<?php $contact_us_node = abc_drupal_node_load(NULL,
'my_group'
);if (isset($contact_us_node->field_contact_us_message_body)) {echo $contact_us_node->field_contact_us_message_body[0][
'value'
] .
"<br />"
;}?></div>
') WHERE nid=123'
```

This is absolutely not what you intended. We have *three levels of escaping*:

1. The Perl string
2. The shell
3. The SQL
4. (The PHP code, but it doesn't use any escapes here)

How can we solve this? We can remove the shell level by having Perl `exec` the command directly without passing it to the shell. For this, we use the list form of that command:

```
system(
  $drushcmd,
  '-r', $drupalroot,
  '-u', 'sites.admin',
  '--yes',
  'sql-query',
  "update node_revisions set body = REPLACE\(body,\'</div>\',\'<?php \$contact_us_node = abc_drupal_node_load\(NULL, \'my_group\'\);if \(isset\(\$contact_us_node->field_contact_us_message_body\)\) {echo \$contact_us_node->field_contact_us_message_body[0][\'value\'] . \"<br />\";}?></div>\'\) WHERE nid=123'",
) == 0 or die "$drushcmd failed: $?";
```

Ah yes, this is better. We can further eliminate the need for escaping inside the Perl code by using single quoted strings with an alternative delimiter:

```
q#update node_revisions set body = REPLACE(body,'</div>','<?php $contact_us_node = abc_drupal_node_load(NULL, 'my_group');if (isset($contact_us_node->field_contact_us_message_body)) {echo $contact_us_node->field_contact_us_message_body[0]['value'] . "<br />";}?></div>') WHERE nid=123'#
```

We have now eliminated the escaping levels for Perl and the shell, so only SQL is left.

Comment: I did the system section and got this error:  ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'hospital_gr

Comment: @DonSevcik yes, the SQL is still invalid, and you have to add necessary escaping.

Comment: I'm lost now.  The query was working on it's own. I still get the same error:

system(
  $drushcmd,
  '-r', $drupalroot,
  '-u', 'sites.admin',
  '--yes',
  'sql-query',
  "update node_revisions set body = REPLACE(body,'</div>','<?php \$contact_us_node = hs2_drupal_node_load(NULL, \'hospital_group\');if (isset(\$contact_us_node->field_contact_us_message_body)) {echo \$contact_us_node->field_contact_us_message_body[0][\'value\'] . \"<br />\";}?></div>') WHERE nid=529",
) == 0 or die "$drushcmd failed: $?";